# Get appsettings.json values without a constructor call in C# .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings, constructor-injection

I have a class that came from an older pre .NET Core project and I'm trying to get it to read appsettings.json data. The catch is that it gets called in a way that does not appear to evoke a constructor, so the usual `IOptions<AppSettings>` constructor injection approach does not work.

The class is called from this method:

```
 private static string GetItemUrl(string language, string itemId)
    {
        return LinkHelp.Instance.Builder.BuildEditItemUrl(language, itemId);
    }
```

And that flows right into the following method:

```
private LinkHelp()
    {
        // Various attempts at getting a config setting here
        var linkBuilderoptions = new ContentManagementHelpersOptions() { ProjectId = projectId };
        Builder = new LinkBuil(linkBuildoptions);         
    }
```

The method did use the old pre-core AppSettingProvider.ProjectId method to get the project Id from a web.config:

```
var projectId = AppSettingProvider.ProjectId.ToString() ?? AppSettingProvider.DefaultProjectId.ToString();
```

Do I need to just add a web.config to the project and continue using the old method? Or is there a way to make this work with .Net Core 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one of those issues where you leave on a Friday after a long week and the simple answer doesn't come to you until after the weekend. Oh well.

Configuration Injection didn't work on the LinkHelp() class - and the project already has a configuration defined. But all that was needed was to make a few small changes to pass the configuration on from the calling class to the receiving class.

```
public LinkHelp(string projectId)
    {
        var linkBuilderoptions = new ContentManagementHelpersOptions() { ProjectId = projectId };
        Builder = new LinkBuil(linkBuildoptions);         
    }
```

And then call that class in a slightly new way (this class already has access to the configs):

```
private static string GetItemUrl(string language, string itemId)
{
    projectId = ProjectOptions.OptionsList.ProjectId;
    var editLink = LinkHelp(propjectId).Instance.Builder.BuildEditItemUrl(language, itemId);
    return editLink
}
```

And that appears to have worked. It didn't require too many additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can access you configuration during bootstrapping like so.

This is what your "Program" might look like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

In your startup class you can get an implementation of the `IConfiguration` injected like so:

```
public class Startup : ServiceStartup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var yourConfiguration = new YourOwnConfigurationClass();
        _configuration.Bind(nameof(YourOwnConfigurationClass), yourConfiguration );
        services.AddSingleton(yourConfiguration )
    }
}
```

In this case your config.json should contain a property name corresponding with the name of your class name `YourOwnConfigurationClass`. The properties in your `YourOwnConfigurationClass` should correspond with the properties assinged to the property called YourOwnConfigurationClass.

Now is `YourConfigurationClass` injectable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have an injectable configuration class. My issue is that I'm calling a class that does not invoke a constructor, so the injectable class isn't functioning.